# Angular Material vs Angular Cdk - which is better to use for an Angular app

Tags: angular, angular-material, contextmenu, angular-cdk, angular16

I have an angular project using ng2-right-click-menu for context menu
Since with Angular 16 its not compatible, i have to switch to an alternative solution
When i searched for Angular material menu

```
<mat-menu>
```

came across Angular CDK menu.

```
import {CdkMenuModule} from '@angular/cdk/menu;
```

Confused which one to use for my application.
As the menu should be customizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material actually extends the CDK, but adds stying and themes. Notice how the [CDK menu](https://material.angular.io/cdk/menu/examples) is pretty basic looking. The [Material menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview) has a bit more functionality, and it can be themed.

I would suggest you go with Material, unless you want to create your own look and lose the themeing ability, then use the CDK.

Comment: Hi @inorganik Thanks the clarification. I think i will go with CDK menu since we have a basic context menu in our application.